# 'CXXABI_1.3.11' not found`

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, automake

I can't get a cross compiled build running on my Raspberry Pi 1 B+. The error I keep getting is:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.11'
```

not found. I tried multiple compilers with different settings but I keep getting the same error. Also changing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the location of libstdc++ on my Pi didn't work. Today I got a sort of breakthrough finding out that the make process outputs "will change in GCC 7.1" after an argument. I'm not a hundred percent sure that this is what cause the error, but GCC 7.1 comes with version 1.3.11 of `CXXABI`, so I suspect it to be the cause. Is there anybody that knows how to stop this from happening? I'm building on a VM with Ubuntu 17.10. I'm building using `sh autogen.sh; ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf; make -j8`

Thanks

Edit: Found the solution myself, it was: `export CXX=/path/to/toolchain/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`

Answer (score 0):

Your cross-GCC comes with a version of `libstdc++.so` which is not compatible with the one installed on your system. You can either run compiled program with modified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or `-Wl,-rpath`), pointing to directory with cross-compiler's `libstdc++.so`, or downgrade your cross-compiler to match your distro.